# Not able to correctly plot x-axis in HighChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am new to highChart and even after following the documentation I am not able to correctly plot the x-axis. It only labels the the first element of the dateAndTimeArray array.Can you please tell me where I am making mistake. Here is my code.

JSON Array

```
  var jsonObj=[ {
  name:"Nov-10 18:00",
  data:[50],
  type:'column'
},
            {
  name:"Nov-20 20:00",
  data:[60],
  type:'column'
},
            {
  name:"Nov-10 22:00",
  data:[70],
  type:'column'
},
            {
  name:"Nov-12 20:00",
  data:[80],
  type:'column'
}]
```

HighChart related code

```
dateAndTimeArray = ['Nov-15 18:00', 'Nov-20 20:00', 'Nov-11 22:00', 'Nov-12 20:00'];

     var seriesData=jsonObj;
console.log(seriesData);
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy',
            spacingRight: 10
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            showFirstLabel: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true,
            categories: dateAndTimeArray,
            tickInterval: 00,
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value.toString().substring(0, 6);
                },
                rotation: 0.1,
                align: 'left',
                step: 10,
                enabled: true
            },
            style: {
                fontSize: '8px'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Measurement value'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: {
                        x1: 0,
                        y1: 0,
                        x2: 0,
                        y2: 1
                    },
                    stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                shadow: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                //  threshold: null
            }
        },
        series:jsonObj


    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4xafjr4b/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart is plotting what you asked it to. You have 4 series of data. Each series has one data point. I think you confusing the `series.name` and xAxis point. Since each of your series has just one point it is assigned to the first category in your `xAxis.categories`.

The question then becomes:
Do you want to have a categorical xAxis or a datetime xAxis?

Your data leads itself to categorical but your `xAxis.categories` don't line up with your `series.name` entries and your `xAxis.categories` are not in ascending time order. You also are setting a categorical list of items but telling highcharts that your chart is `type: 'datetime'`. You need to pick one.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/4xafjr4b/1/) is an example using categorical type.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/ejmLkp6v/) is an example using datetime type.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing it out, but just one more doubt, I think in the first case will we be able to have different colors for each of the column?

Comment: it is possible to add different colors also.Have to add colorByPoint: true, Thanks you very much.